# Enviar Array Javascript para Controller via POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando enviar um `Array` de `int` do `JavaScript` para o `Controller` via `POST`.
Veja meu array:

```
console.debug(itens);

Array [ 1, 2 ]
```

Estou tentando enviar da seguinte forma:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("MinhaAction", "MeuController")', { MeuParametro : itens })
```

MeuController está assim:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MinhaAction(int[] MeuParametro)
```

Mas ao debugar, tenho recebido null em meu controller, pois ao invés de enviar:

```
MeuParametro : [1,2]
```

O JavaScript tem enviado:

```
MeuParametro[] : "1"
MeuParametro[] : "2"
```

Tentei usar **JSON.parse()**:

```
 $.post('@Url.Action("MinhaAction", "MeuController")', { MeuParametro : JSON.parse(itens) })
```

E tem funcionado apenas quando tenho apenas um item em meu array, mas quando tenho dois ou mais (como é o meu caso), o seguinte erro é retornado:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after
>   JSON data at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data  jquery-1.8.2.js line
>   578 > eval:126:71

Alguém poderia me ajudar nisso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funcionou seguindo a dica dessas respostas:

- [Resposta1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489461/pass-array-to-mvc-action-via-ajax)
- [Resposta2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497093/what-is-traditional-style-of-param-serialization-in-jquery)
- [Resposta3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109544/how-can-i-send-int-array-from-ajax-to-c-sharp-mvc)

Usando:

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```

O problema é que as configurações são globais. Caso queira algo diferente em outro post, isto causará problemas.

Assim, pude usar normalmente:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("MinhaAction", "MeuController")', { MeuParametro : itens })
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, Grande tenta também criar um padrão na tua variável itens, mais ou menos assim, itens.id, por ai no caso quando for enviar pro controller ele vai identificar relamente um json:

```
itens:{
    {"id":"1"},
    {"id":"2"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma :

```
var countryArray = [1,2,3,4];

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Home/SaveTable",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ MeuParametro : countryArray}),
    });
```

Ou seja, ao invés de fazer `JSON.parse(array)` você terá que fazer `JSON.stringify({ MeuParametro : countryArray}`

**Diferença entre JSON.parse e JSON.stringify**

De acordo com o Livro 'Json básico' de Ben Smith "há um método stringify que gera JASON serializado a partir de um dado.". Logo após informa que há um método que é o oposto de stringify "Esse método é conhecido como 'parse'. Em poucas palavras, JSON.parce converte JSON serializado em valores JavaScript"

[Link livro](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=aGOsCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=diferen%C3%A7a%20entre%20JSON.parse%20a%20JSON.stringify&source=bl&ots=x4GfDZXuRy&sig=oADv-xwsGn5mhNd9Jl893mDD6WI&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CFQQ6AEwB2oVChMI4bjhkf2_yAIVyKceCh0WIgNU#v=onepage&q=diferen%C3%A7a%20entre%20JSON.parse%20a%20JSON.stringify&f=false)

Links importantes :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785592/difference-between-json-stringify-and-json-parse

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288462/c-sharp-mvc-4-passing-javascript-array-in-view-to-controller

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497093/what-is-traditional-style-of-param-serialization-in-jquery/5497151#5497151

Comment: Bem amigo, muito obrigado pela resposta, mas a questão é que eu gostaria de usar o método `$.post` ao invés do `$.ajax`.

Comment: Na verdade o método $.post é derivado de $.ajax. porem com algumas simplificações. Vou verificar a possibilidade de usar o $.post e posto um nova resposta.